# How can I use django's default test framework to test a module included in sys.path that is not a subdirectory of the django project?

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-unittest, django-tests

I have a django (1.8) site that is structured like this:

```
.../django_project/
    ./templates/
    ./manage.py
    ./<dir with settings,urls,etc>
.../django_app_project/
    ./app_name/
        ./<app files>
        ./test_app.py
```

To run the site, I set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH=.../django_app_project/`.  This works perfectly when running the server, but causes problems when running the tests.  Django's DiscoverRunner (`django.test.runner.DiscoverRunner`) does not notice `.../Django_app_project/app_name/test_app.py`.  How can this be made to work without moving the app into the Django project? (It is outside for version control reasons)

Comment: Is that app listed in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, it is listed there.